# how do I empty/clear vector and array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, iterator

let's say I have a class, A

```
Class A {
  int x[100];
  vector<int> y;
  Fill(x);
  Fill(y.begin());
  B(x);
  B(y.begin());
}
Class Fill (pointer) {
  *pointer = 0;
  ++pointer;
  *pointer = 1;
  ++pointer 
}
Class B(container) {
  //how do I clear/empty the array and the vector passed by class A given only the pointers to them?
  //I must clear an array and a vector in THIS class.
  //I DO NOT want to fill them with 0s. 
  //x and y.begin are POINTERS to the first element of the container, not containers    
}
```

dsfsdakfgnsdfgsf
dg
sdf
gsdf
ghsdf
g
sdfg
ersg
s

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by clearing the array ?

Comment: If the array has [1,2,3,4] then I want to make it [].

Comment: Well.. the syntax isn't really valid for starters. Consider fixing that.

Comment: You can't do that. Arrays cannot be resized after they have been declared.

Comment: Classes are not functions.

Comment: It would be nice if the code you presented at least had valid syntax. `Class Fill (pointer) {` is not valid (same for `Class B(containers)`

Answer (score 1):

For vector:

```
some_a_pointer->y.resize(0);
```

You can't do it with just an iterator (`y.begin()`).

An array's size can never change, so the best you can do is fill it with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has a method called `clear` that will clear all the elements.

So `my_vector.clear();` will clear everything. However you can't really do the same for arrays. It's just not possible. At best you can fill them with zeroes or go the wrong way and dynamically allocate the array and then delete it. I would rather not deal with memory issues though so I'd just fill them with zero.

C++11 has a class called `std::array<T,N>` for static arrays of a compile time size and it has a method called `fill` that would make filling everything to zero easy (a la looping). You can call it with `my_array.fill(0);`.

Comment: The problem is in class B, I only have the pointers to both array and vector. I obviously can't call 'clear' on a pointer.

Comment: @Nayana What you want to do is impossible.

Comment: @Nayana consider your approach as bad design. better put allocate/deallocate as owner class responsibility, you should implement those functions in `class A`

Comment: @Nayana: Do you have a pointer to the vector, or just a pointer/iterator to its elements?

Comment: @BenVoigt He mentioned earlier it's just an iterator.